# Como implementar Interceptor en Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Tengo el siguiente código en mi interceptor:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
  if (token && token != null) {
    request = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        authorization: `bearer20 ${ token }`
      }
    });
  } else {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    return next.handle(request);  
  }
}
export const interceptorProvider = [{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptorService, multi: true}];
```

Y se implementa en app.module.ts:

```
providers:[     
  interceptorProvider                               
]
```

El detalle es que no funciona, tampoco sale error.

Espero su respuesta, gracias, saludos

Comment: cual es el error que obtienes

Comment: Estimado no sale ningun, error, el detalle es que no agarra el interceptor

Answer (score 1):

En realidad tu interceptor **SI** está funcionando, lo que ocurre es que una vez dentro de él hay una condición que no ejecuta

```
return next.handle(request);
```

En los interceptors tu debes hacer una de estas dos cosas

1. Fabricar manualmente un `Observable` conteniendo tu propia respuesta usando [`HttpResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse)
2. retornar un `Observable` con el resultado de ejecutar `next.handle(request)`

Por supuesto que puedes mutar el `request` todo lo que quieras antes de ejecutarlo.

La solución sería:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    if (token && token != null) {
        request = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                authorization: `bearer20 ${ token }`
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login'); 
    }
    // en todos los casos ejecutas la petición
    return next.handle(request);
}
```

El otro error que puedes tener es que el bearer token no lo estás poniendo bien. El formato correcto es `Authorization: Bearer xxx`. Debería ser:

```
request = req.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${ token }`
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

parece que tu objeto interceptorProvider ya es un array, y al momento de declararlo en providers le pones nuevamente corchetes, por que no pruebas poniendo así:

```
providers: interceptorProvider // sin corchetes
```